# JPEG encoder and decoder and send via socket C#

Tags: c#, image-compression

I have some picture send via sockets to the client. 
these pictures must be compressed before sending to the client .
what can i do for compressing to jpeg and send via socket (convert jpeg to byte[] send to the client and vice versa).
thanks for help.
====edit :
these are some blocks of an image , with 24bpp pixel format

Comment: Let's get the question clear: do you have a different image format you need to convert to Jpeg, or do you have a Jpeg you need to read into a byte array?

Comment: _I have some picture_ Where do these images come from? What format are they?

Comment: these are some blocks of an image , with 24bpp pixel format

Comment: JPEGs are already compressed + they are binary data. Compressing those further is pretty hard. You might want to try to base64 the binary data and zip that ... but i highly doubt there will be any benefit in space saved..

Answer (score 0):

Use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_IO_Stream_System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageFormat_ (assuming you're using the full framework).

Edit: that should have pointed to the overload using an ImageCodecInfo on that same page. Unless the images are already compressed JPEGs, in which case don't recompress them - you'll only decrease quality.